# Add class to element depending on which side of the screen its on

Tags: javascript, position, wordpress-theming, addclass

I am making a timeline theme and need to have a separate class for the posts on the right side of the screen and the left side of the screen. I don't see anything wrong with my javascript but of course its not working.

```
var halfScreenWidth = jQuery(document).width() * 0.5;
var timelinePost = jQuery('.blog .post');

jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    timelinePost.each( function(){
       if( this.position().left < halfScreenWidth ){
           jQuery(this).addClass('timeline-left');
       } else{
           jQuery(this).addClass('timeline-right');
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made a few modifications at https://jsfiddle.net/zLv4s0ur/26/ .

`if( this.position().left < halfScreenWidth )`

should be

`if( jQuery(this).position().left < halfScreenWidth )`